# selecting (filtering) records matching a day,start and end filter list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mysqli

i actually want to fileter my result of dates matching another list. this filter list has (can have) multiple records of day of week, starting time and ending time. so this should help selecting only the results that match these times and days. but as i mentioned these may be multiple times o only one record. i need a fast and efficient way to do this because dates will be very crowded. 
my additional question is should i do this with sql query or would it be better to do that with php?

this is the example of the dates. as "Y-m-d H:i:s" standard.

```
dates
2014-10-31 01:20:08
2014-11-01 09:22:08
2014-11-10 09:24:08
2014-11-13 09:26:08
2014-11-14 09:28:08
```

this is an example of the times and day. (ISO-8601 1 for monday though 7 for sunday)

```
day     timeStart    timeEnd
0       01:00:00     05:00:00
1       01:00:00     05:00:00
2       01:00:00     05:00:00
4       01:00:00     05:00:00
7       01:00:00     05:00:00
```

this is what i want the result to look like. only the date that matches the filter list

```
result
2014-10-31 01:20:08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if Monday = 1 and Sunday = 7, then 0 must also mean Sunday.

So to find the matches, you need to link the tables in two ways:

**1. Find the day of the week for the date and match it to day**

You can find the day of the week using the [`WEEKDAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function. As the docs say, Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6, which is 1 day out for your range. Also you apparently need to take into account that you can have 0 and 7.

So to match on `WEEKDAY` you need to take 1 off `day` then normalise it to a range of 1 - 7 using [`modulus %`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod). Bear in mind that `0 - 1` will return `-1`, so add 7 to ensure it is positive:

```
where WEEKDAY(d.theDate) = ((dr.day + 7) - 1) % 7
```

**2. Ensure the time of the day is between `timeStart` and `timeEnd`**

This is much simpler and just requires using the [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to convert the date into a time and then check it is between the two times:

```
where TIME(d.theDate) between dr.timeStart and dr.timeEnd
```

**Putting it together**

Putting these two things together you can use a fairly simple join to find the matches:

```
select d.theDate from dates as d
  inner join dateRanges as dr on WEEKDAY(d.theDate) = ((dr.day + 7)-1)%7
    and TIME(d.theDate) between dr.timeStart and dr.timeEnd
```

Here is a SQLFiddle as an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ad80/4